# SQL Joins with email, domains, and limits

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to return email alias domain quantity and limit information. I am having trouble figuring out the SQL statement.

I have four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE person 
  ( 
     person_id   VARCHAR2(9 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     internal_id VARCHAR2(9 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE 
  )

INSERT INTO person 
VALUES      ('012345678', 
             '987654321')

INSERT INTO person 
VALUES      ('24680123', 
             '32108642')

CREATE TABLE group 
  ( 
     internal_id VARCHAR2(9 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     group_id    VARCHAR2(30 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE 
  )

INSERT INTO group 
VALUES      ('987654321', 
             'alumni')

INSERT INTO group 
VALUES      ('987654321', 
             'retiree')

INSERT INTO group 
VALUES      ('32108642', 
             'random')

INSERT INTO group 
VALUES      ('987654321', 
             'other')

CREATE TABLE email_alias 
  ( 
     person_id   VARCHAR2(9 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     email_alias VARCHAR2(70 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE 
  )

INSERT INTO email_alias 
VALUES      ('012345678', 
             'person@school.edu')

INSERT INTO email_alias 
VALUES      ('012345678', 
             'per_son@school.edu')

INSERT INTO email_alias 
VALUES      ('012345678', 
             'person@random.com')

INSERT INTO email_alias 
VALUES      ('012345678', 
             'random@random.com')

CREATE TABLE domain_limit 
  ( 
     group_id     VARCHAR2(30 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     alias_domain VARCHAR2(30 byte) NOT NULL ENABLE,
     limit        NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE
  )

INSERT INTO domain_limit 
VALUES      ('retiree', 
             '@school.edu',
             5)

INSERT INTO domain_limit 
VALUES      ('retiree', 
             '@school.net',
             2)

INSERT INTO domain_limit 
VALUES      ('employee', 
             '@school.edu',
             25)

INSERT INTO domain_limit 
VALUES      ('employee', 
             '@school.net',
             2)

INSERT INTO domain_limit 
VALUES      ('alumni', 
             '@school.net',
             2)

INSERT INTO domain_limit 
VALUES      ('student', 
             '@school.edu',
             1)

INSERT INTO domain_limit 
VALUES      ('student', 
             '@school.net',
             2)
```

I want to display something like the following:

```
quantity | alias_domain  | limit 
--------------------------------
2        | @random.com   | 0
0        | @school.net   | 25
0        | @school.edu   | 2
```

Part of the problem is that someone may have entered an `email_alias` that doesn't match with one of the domains in the table because there was no regex in place at one point. We use the groups to which a person belongs to determine the maximum number of aliases they may have. They may belong to more than one group that grants them access to aliases of the same domain. We don't add them together but instead select the max limit for a given domain.

I can get it to either display

```
quantity | alias_domain  | limit 
--------------------------------
2        | @random.com   | 0
```

or

```
quantity | alias_domain  | limit 
--------------------------------
0        | @school.net   | 25
0        | @school.edu   | 2
```

but other things I try wind up with

```
quantity | alias_domain  | limit 
--------------------------------
2        | @school.net   | 25
2        | @school.edu   | 2
```

here is a sample of something I have tried:

```
select count(regexp_substr(lower(d.email_alias), c.alias_domain)) as "quantity", 
         c.alias_domain  as "alias_domain", 
         nvl(max(c.limit), 0)  as "limit" 
  from   iam.person a 
         left join groups b 
                on a.internal_id = b.internal_id 
         join domain_limit c 
           on b.group_id = c.group_id 
         left join iam.email_alias d 
                on a.person_id = d.person_id 
  where  a.person_id = :PERSON_ID 
  group  by c.alias_domain
```

I have also tried something like:

```
select count(regexp_substr(lower(d.email_alias), c.alias_domain)) as "quantity", 
             nvl(c.alias_domain, regexp_substr(d.email_alias, '@.+')) as "alias_domain", 
             nvl(max(c.limit), 0) as "limit"     
from   iam.person a 
       left join groups b 
            on a.internal_id = b.internal_id 
       join domain_limit c 
            on b.group_id = c.group_id 
       left join iam.email_alias d 
            on a.person_id = d.person_id 
where  a.person_id = :PERSON_ID 
group  by nvl(c.alias_domain, regexp_substr(d.email_alias, '@.+'))
```

When I use the following code

```
select distinct 
count(nvl(c.alias_domain, regexp_substr(d.email_alias, '@.+'))) as quantity,
nvl(c.alias_domain, regexp_substr(d.email_alias, '@.+')) as alias_domain,
nvl(max(c.limit),0) as limit
from person a
join group b
on a.internal_id = b.internal_id
left join domain_limit c
on b.group_id = c.group_id
left join email_alias d
on a.person_id = d.person_id
where a.person_id = :PERSON_ID
group by nvl(c.alias_domain, regexp_substr(d.email_alias, '@.+'));
```

I get

```
quantity | domain | limit
--------------------------
2   | @school.edu   | 25
6   | @school.net   | 2
96  | @random.com   | 0
```

In my set I have 2 random.com emails. And 48 groups. 1 group that gives me a limit of 25 school.edu and 3 groups that give me a limit of 2 school.net aliases.

I wound up solving it using this

```
select max(quantity) as quantity,
alias_domain, max(limit)
from (select count(email_alias) as quantity,
regexp_substr(email_alias, '@.+') as alias_domain,
0 as limit
from email_alias
where person_id = :PERSON_ID
group by regexp_substr(email_alias, '@.+'), 0
union
select 0 as quantity,
alias_domain,
max(limit)
from iam.person a
join gro.person_group b
on a.person_id = b.person_id
join domain_limit c
on b.group_id = c.group_id
where a.person_id = :PERSON_ID
group by alias_domain, 0)
group by alias_domain;
```

If you see a cleaner way of doing it let me know thanks.

Comment: What is "domain quantity"?  What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Test case might be useful, so - if you could provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO several sample records, we could try your code ourselves and - hopefully - improve it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "Domain quantity" is the number of email aliases that a person has of the given domain. Limit is the maximum number that they are supposed to have. As for the problem, I have given examples of what I want it to look like and what is it displaying instead.

Comment: @Littlefoot I edited and added the creates and inserts as you requested thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is your issue? Is it because your current queries return a subset and not all of desired results? I am seeing a parameter placeholder, `:PERSON_ID` possibly inputted at application layer like Python or PHP. This could be subsetting your results.

Comment: @Parfait `:PERSON_ID` is a bound variable used in oracle to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I need to figure out some way of counting the email aliases with a given domain without having domains disappear to show what domain limits a person is supposed to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max(quantity) as quantity,
alias_domain, max(limit)
from (select count(email_alias) as quantity,
regexp_substr(email_alias, '@.+') as alias_domain,
0 as limit
from email_alias
where person_id = :PERSON_ID
group by regexp_substr(email_alias, '@.+'), 0
union
select 0 as quantity,
alias_domain,
max(limit)
from iam.person a
join gro.person_group b
on a.person_id = b.person_id
join domain_limit c
on b.group_id = c.group_id
where a.person_id = :PERSON_ID
group by alias_domain, 0)
group by alias_domain;
```